# How can I verify token and get user details?

Tags: node.js, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api, keycloak-connect

I implemented keycloak in my Node.js application. For login, I used API:

```
http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

It returns the login user's token if the username and password are correct.

Now I need to pass this token(returned by the above API) and check whether this token is correct or not, and if the token is correct I need user details, is there any API for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now I need to pass this token(return by above API) and check this
> token is correct or not

You will need to use the `introspection endpoint` from the Keycloak Documentation:

**token_introspection_endpoint**

> A OAuth2-compliant Token Introspection Endpoint which clients can use
> to query the server to determine the active state of an RPT and to
> determine any other information associated with the token, such as the
> permissions granted by Keycloak.
>
> and if token is correct I need user details, is there any API for
> this.

For that you need to use the **userinfo_endpoint**.

Both endpoints can be found under the following link:

```
{KEYCLOAK_URL}/auth/realms/{REALM_NAME}/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

or since the `/auth` path was removed starting with [Keycloak 17 Quarkus distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71902419/1366871):

```
{KEYCLOAK_URL}/realms/{REALM_NAME}/.well-known/openid-configuration
```